# Update Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10 - black screen

Tags: upgrade, 15.10

I have just bought a Dell "Inspiron 15 3552U" with Ubuntu 14.04 pre-installed. I made all the software update, and the system now proposes me to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10. My goal is to have the last version 16.04 in the end.

I try to launch the upgrade simply by accepting it when the system proposes from the desktop or the software update manager. My computer doing the rest...

I manage to download all packages, but I get a black screen during the installation (more or less in the middle of the process).

My question is therefore: should I wait and my computer will wake up with a brand new version of Ubuntu one day? Should I force the shut down and press the power button? I know this is not the solution. Last time I tried, I had to restore the factory settings to be able use my computer again. Ubuntu was not launching and I got something like the Ubuntu terminal with commands to enter.

I am totally new with Ubuntu, so any help and guidance would be very welcome.

Many thanks for your help,

Dimitri

Comment: Did you try to move the mouse? It may be a screen saver. If the upgrade fails, you can do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds familiar to me.

This usually happen if the graphics driver is partially compatible, 
incorrectly installed packages, or just a bad computer configuration.

I would wait for a few hours (if you have a good internet conection like 20 MB/s or better). Maybe in 2 hours it could react to your mouse/keyboard.

If that doesn't work, as @Pilot6 said, you can do a totally fresh installation to Ubuntu 16.04. (This could be the best solution.)

Comment: Many thanks, so I will wait a bit then. Otherwise, I have to check how to run a fresh installation as you advised, but not sure how to do this!